# Create Multiple Child Records from Parent Record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two custom objects: Parent (Parent__c) and Child (Child__c). The goal here is for the user to click a button on the Child Related List and enter data in input fields to create new Child records.

Here's my code:

Controller:

```
public class AddingChildController {
Id parentId;
public List<Child__c> childList {get;set;}
public Integer rowNum{get;set;}

public AddingChildController(){
    Id childId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('childId');
    childList = new List<Child__c>();
    childList.add(new Child__c());
}


public void insertChild(){
    insert childList;
}

public void insertRow(){
    childList.add(new Child__c());
}

public void delRow(){
    rowNum = 
Integer.valueof(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));
    childList.remove(rowNum);
}
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AddingChildController" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}" />
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}" />
        <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!childList}" var="int">
        <apex:facet name="footer">
            <apex:commandLink value="Add" action="{!insertRow}"/>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:inputField value="{!int.Name}"/>                                      
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Age">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Age__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Delete">
            <apex:commandLink style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;color:red;" value="X" action="{!delRow}">
                <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:PageBlockTable>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!insertChild}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I've created the button and I can see the Visualforce page, but when I got to save the records, I get the following error:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]: [Parent]
>   Error is in expression '{!insertChild}' in component  in page addchildrenvfpage: Class.AddingChildController.insertChild: line 14, column 1

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

*NEW VERSION**

```
 public class AddingChildController {
 Id parentId;
 public List<Child__c> childList {get;set;}
 public Integer rowNum{get;set;}

public AddingChildController(){
Id parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parentId');
childList = new List<Child__c>();
childList.add(new Child__c(Parent__c = parentId));
   }

public void insertChild(){
    insert childList;
   }

public void insertRow(){
   childList.add(new Child__c(Parent__c = parentId));
    }

public void delRow(){
rowNum = 
Integer.valueof(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));
    childList.remove(rowNum);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your objects are in a master-detail relationship, so the child cannot be created without a parent. In your constructor, as you create your child objects, you're not populating that parent lookup:

```
public AddingChildController(){
    Id childId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('childId');
    childList = new List<Child__c>();
    childList.add(new Child__c());
}
```

There should be a line in here like

```
    childList.add(new Child__c(Parent__c = parentId));
```

In order to do that, you have to *have* the parent's Id. If your page is designed to take the Id of the parent object in the `childId` URL parameter, you'd use that value.

A similar change would need to be made to `insertRow()`.

### Working Minimal Example

I used the Account and Contact sObjects as an example and stripped this down to the essential functionality. I'm able to insert new child records with this page and controller.

#### Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="TestQ232413Controller" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!childList}" var="int">
                <apex:facet name="footer">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Add" action="{!insertRow}"/>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:column headerValue="FN">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!int.FirstName}"/>                                      
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="LN">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!int.LastName}"/>                                      
                </apex:column>
            </apex:PageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!insertChild}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

#### Controller

```
public class TestQ232413Controller {
    Id parentId;
    public List<Contact> childList {get;set;}

    public TestQ232413Controller(){
        Id parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parentId');
        childList = new List<Contact>();
        childList.add(new Contact(AccountId = parentId));
    }

    public void insertChild(){
        insert childList;
    }

    public void insertRow(){
        childList.add(new Contact(AccountId = parentId));
    }
}
```

### List Button on Contact

Content Source: URL, `/apex/TestQ232413?parentId={!Account.Id}`

Comment: thanks david!!! this is awesome!!! it's working and creating the child records! one final question: how do i return to the parent object after clicking save?

Comment: @KatieZinman, that's a good separate question (search `PageReference` first, though - might find you everything you need!)

Comment: I've spent a few hours trying to figure out how to add PageReference here and can't seem to get it to work. Anyway you could point me in the right direction?